# Shared cookies with WKProcessPool for WKWebView in Swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, process-pool

Can anyone please tell me how to create a WKProcessPool in Swift? I'm not familiar with Objective-C.
I have to create a WKProcessPool in order to have shared cookies with all WKWebViews. I want to keep cookies even when showing another viewcontroller with same class. I tried the following but it's not working.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let processPool = WKProcessPool()
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.processPool = WKProcessPool()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use configuration.websiteDataStore property instead of processpool.

For the stored cookies use WKWebsiteDataStore.default() value.
For the  private browsing use WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent().

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eldar! This should be the right solution for me! I tried to implement the WKWebsiteDataStore.default() method. `let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)` But how do I access this configuration from another class, so it will use these cookies in the other WKWebView and stay logged in?

Comment: Is this possible using a segue?

Comment: @Stef You can use property `configuration` to get the initial configuration of webView. WKWebsiteDataStore.default() returns a singleton object. You just need to use this singleton for all newly created web views.

Answer (score 1):

The apple site say:

> If your app creates multiple web views, assign the same WKProcessPool
> object to web views that may safely share a process space. Instantiate
> an instance of this class and assign it to the processPool property of
> each web view’s WKWebViewConfiguration object.

However, you set your `processProtocol` into class `ViewControler`. Then, this is redefined each time the view is instantiate. Do it:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
let processPool = WKProcessPool()

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate { var webView = WKWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.processPool = WKProcessPool()

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
}
```